# How do i change position of a button depending on size of screen in Vuetify

Tags: web, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am looking for a way to change the position of a button depending on what size the screen using Vuetify, the button should be at the bottom right.

[this is the position of the button on a large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y5LS.png)

[This is the position on a smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhT9L.png)

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is pretty much impossible to see what is going on there.  Can you replicate it in a codepen or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the first answer said you have to use breakpoint. Here is an example.

```
<v-flex xs12 md6 class="text-xs-right">
    <v-btn :block="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly" flat>Cancel</v-btn>
    <v-btn :block="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly" color="primary" @click="onSave()">Save</v-btn>
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "Breakpoint" this will allow you to apply specific properties based upon your viewport size.

```
export default {  
  computed: {
    position () {
      switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
        case 'xs': return 'your position'
        case 'sm': return 'your position'
        case 'md': return 'your position'
        case 'lg': return 'your position'
        case 'xl': return 'your position'
      }
    }
  }
}
```